# php converting number

Tags: php, number-formatting

Let's say I have numbers like

```
123456000000
12345000000
123456000
123456
```

and I want them to show up as

```
123.45B
12.345B
123.45M
123,456
```

The best way I can think of to do this is by getting *string length* to determine if I need a B, M, or nothing but commas and just `substr` the first five chars. I'm sure there is a better way though and I don't want to get too far before I realize that my idea sucks. hah.

Any good recommendations?

**EDIT**

My apologies on the confusion of the B and M. Those represent:

- **B** illion
- **M** illion

Comment: Probably won't completely solve your problem but [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) might be able to help. Also this comment on the same page http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#89888

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so my previous answer considered you were dealing with file sizes, and I deleted it. However the logic of this solution is the same:

```
function format_number($num) {
     if($num < 1000000) {
        return number_format($num);
     } elseif ($num < 1000000000) {
        return number_format($num/1000000, 2) . 'M';
     } else {
        return number_format($num/1000000000, 2) . 'B';
     }
}
```

http://codepad.org/nb89ze5J

Comment: @Jackson, now I noticed it does not return what you wanted for the second number (it's giving 12.35B instead of 12.354B), but I believe this code should work as a starting point anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the last `B` or `M` part but there is a function called [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in PHP which does the following (from the documentation) -

```
$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Comment: I added some more clarification on the B and M abbreviations in my question edit. I failed to evaluate the clarity of my question correctly :(

Comment: @Jackson: Then take a look at this comment on the same page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#89888